# Does Entity Framework 4 work with SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, compatibility

Does ADO.NET Entity Framework 4 work with SQL Server 2005?

I'm having trouble getting EF to work and I'm wondering if it's because of our version of SQL Server.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the trouble you're experiencing?  Error messages, behaviours, VS 2010 RTM etc...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, EF4 does work with SQL Server 2005.

Comment: I'm not convinced it does - It forced me to install Sql Server 2k8 express

Comment: @Carnotaurus: Florian is right. VS will install SQL Server, but not for the EF.